# I created a Microsoft Azure Function that gathers data from a weather API. Then the data is stored to MYSQL. Trouble creating NEW API

Tags: mysql, json, azure, api, express

I created a Microsoft Azure Function app that gathers data from a weather API. The data is parsed and then stored into Microsoft Azure's Mysql database/server. I am trying to create a new API that gets the contents from the database and gives me a API url to access some data. I tried creating a express rest api in the function but had no luck.

Does anyone have any experience in this that could help?

Best,

Joshua

I tried to use some express code. I was receiving no output/ was not generating a URL.

Comment: `I tried creating a express rest api in the function` -what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Basically microsoft azure gives us api link. But I don't want to use that so that I am able to monitor/track the API. I tried to add some express code which generates a new API as follows: "azurefuncname.azurewebsites.net/api/data". I am trying to add my parsed data into the app.get('/api/data') so it generates a new endpoint. But I am stuck since it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the MySQL Database

```
CREATE TABLE `weather_data` (
  `address` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `maxt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `mint` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `precip` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `wspd` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `wdir` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `wgust` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `pressure` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Loading the weather data into MySQL

Prerequisites: Python 3.8.2, MySQL Connector for Python, DNSPython
Imports:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import mysql.connector
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
```

Setting up the input parameters:

```
# This is the core of our weather query URL
BaseURL = 'https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/weatherdata/'

ApiKey='INSERT_YOUR_KEY_HERE'
#UnitGroup sets the units of the output - us or metric
UnitGroup='us'

#Locations for the weather data. Multiple locations separated by pipe (|)
Locations='Washington,DC'

#FORECAST or HISTORY
QueryType='FORECAST'

#1=hourly, 24=daily
AggregateHours='24'

#Params for history only
StartDate = ''
EndDate=''
```

Downloading the weather data:

```
# Set up the specific parameters based on the type of query
if QueryType == 'FORECAST':
    print(' - Fetching forecast data')
    QueryParams = 'forecast?aggregateHours=' + AggregateHours + '&unitGroup=' + UnitGroup + '&shortColumnNames=true'
else:
    print(' - Fetching history for date: ', DateParam)

    # History requests require a date.  We use the same date for start and end since we only want to query a single date in this example
    QueryParams = 'history?aggregateHours=' + AggregateHours + '&unitGroup=' + UnitGroup +'&startDateTime=' + StartDate + 'T00%3A00%3A00&endDateTime=' + EndDate + 'T00%3A00%3A00'

Locations='&locations='+Locations

ApiKey='&key='+ApiKey

# Build the entire query
URL = BaseURL + QueryParams + Locations + ApiKey+"&contentType=json"

print(' - Running query URL: ', URL)
print()


response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
data = response.read()
weatherData = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Insert the weather data into our MySQL table:

```
print( "Connecting to mysql database")
#connect to the database. Enter your host, username and password
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
    user='YOUR_USERNAME',
    passwd='YOUR_PASSWORD',
    database='weather_data_schema')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

# In this simple example, clear out the existing data in the table

delete_weather_data=("TRUNCATE TABLE `weather_data_schema`.`weather_data`")
cursor.execute(delete_weather_data)
cnx.commit()
# Create an insert statement for inserting rows of data 
insert_weather_data = ("INSERT INTO `weather_data_schema`.`weather_data`"
                "(`address`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`datetime`,`maxt`,`mint`,`temp`,`precip`,`wspd`,`wdir`,`wgust`,`pressure`)"
                "VALUES (%(address)s, %(latitude)s, %(longitude)s, %(datetime)s, %(maxt)s,%(mint)s, %(temp)s, %(precip)s, %(wspd)s, %(wdir)s, %(wgust)s, %(pressure)s)")
                
# Iterate through the locations
locations=weatherData["locations"]
for locationid in locations:  
    location=locations[locationid]
    # Iterate through the values (values are the time periods in the weather data)
    for value in location["values"]:
        data_wx = {
        'address': location["address"],
        'latitude': location["latitude"],
        'longitude': location["longitude"],
        'datetime': datetime.utcfromtimestamp(value["datetime"]/1000.),
        'maxt':  value["maxt"] if 'maxt' in value else 0,
        'mint': value["mint"] if 'mint' in value else 0,
        'temp': value["temp"],
        'precip': value["precip"],
        'wspd': value["wspd"],
        'wdir': value["wdir"],
        'wgust': value["wgust"],
        'pressure': value["sealevelpressure"]
        }
        cursor.execute(insert_weather_data, data_wx)
        cnx.commit()
               
cursor.close() 
cnx.close()
print( "Database connection closed")

print( "Done")
```

Comment: Hi @Justin Zhao, will this code be creating a new API. I do not want to give our partners access to our direct data from the weather API. So my goal is to generate a new API that allows to access to the same data that is generated from the weather data. Thanks!

Comment: You aren't making sense, how is this API giving your partner access to the direct data from the weather API? This simply stores the data in the database, how you display it to the partner is irrelevant. That's the front-end. Once the data is stored in the database correctly, you can manipulate the view, aka, what the partner sees displayed on his screen.